# Vue and VueRouter creating separate instances of components

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am new to using Vue and Vue Router, but it was easy enough to pick up. Here is the problem I am having currently. I have a VueRouter set up and a component for each path.

When I first load up my app, I try to do an action. In the handView component, I hit a button that pops up a modal, then I hit a button on the modal. Both of these are binded to methods by clicking in the handView component. I console.log the values of certain data and the instance "this" when they are pressed. Here is what it looks like the first time.

```
[Log] VueComponent {_uid: 5, _isVue: true, $options: Object, _renderProxy: Proxy, _self: VueComponent, …} (self.js, line 117)
[Log] 0 2 (self.js, line 118)
[Log] VueComponent {_uid: 5, _isVue: true, $options: Object, _renderProxy: Proxy, _self: VueComponent, …} (self.js, line 122)
[Log] 0 2 (self.js, line 123)
```

The first "0 2" is from the method that actives the model, the second is from the method bound to button click within the modal. Both are reading 0 and 2 for the data I am looking at. They should both be the same.

So then I navigate to another route/component, and I come back and do the exact same thing again. Here is the result.

```
[Log] VueComponent {_uid: 9, _isVue: true, $options: Object, _renderProxy: Proxy, _self: VueComponent, …} (self.js, line 117)
[Log] 0 3 (self.js, line 118)
[Log] VueComponent {_uid: 5, _isVue: true, $options: Object, _renderProxy: Proxy, _self: VueComponent, …} (self.js, line 122)
[Log] 0 1 (self.js, line 123)
```

The first one (_uid: 9), has the correct values, but the modal button (second numbers) has the old values still. I think it has something to do with the fact there are two separate instances of the component now, the _uid: 5 from the first log, and now there is a _uid: 9.

Why is there a new instance being created and it seems to have the proper values, and why is the _uid: 5 being hung onto after a new route/component is navigated to and returned from?

I am using Vue 2.3.2, Semantic UI 2.2.10, and Jquery 3.2.1

Comment: Sounds like an issue a `key` would solve, but can't see enough code to recommend. Can you set up a test bed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was having was without context, Semantic UI will move the modal outside of the div that was holding the app element Vue was using. So my modal was outside of the DOM and that is why it created a new instance for the component, but the old instance was still present for the modal. The solution was to declare a context for the modal. (https://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html#/settings)

Mine looked something like this:

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
  next(function (vm) {
    $(function() {
      $("#player-selector").modal({
        context: "#router-view"
      })
    })
  });
}
```

So before entering the route I set the context to be the div I am working in. That way my inactive/active modal does not move itself outside the context of the component I am working with. This did cause some issues with the dimmer effect that the modals use.